# How override model in Magento correctly?

Tags: magento, overriding

guys.

I need to override 2 functions in different classes (CatalogSearch/Layer.php and CatalogSearch/Mysql4/Fulltext/Collection.php). So, I have a config file:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <my_modulename>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </my_modulename>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalogsearch>
                <rewrite>
                    <layer>My_Modulename_Model_CatalogSearch_Layer</layer>
<mysql4_fulltext_collection>My_Modulename_Model_CatalogSearch_Mysql4_Fulltext_Collection </mysql4_fulltext_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </catalogsearch>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Hence, Layer.php has been overridden correctly , but Collection.php hasn't - '/local/My/Modulename/Model/CatalogSearch/Mysql4/Fulltext/Collection.php' was not even included. Why?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The resource models are probably handled separately, try this:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalogsearch>
            <rewrite>
                <layer>My_Modulename_Model_CatalogSearch_Layer</layer>
            </rewrite>
        </catalogsearch>
        <catalogsearch_mysql4>
            <rewrite>
                <fulltext_collection>My_Modulename_Model_CatalogSearch_Mysql4_Fulltext_Collection</fulltext_collection>
            </rewrite>
        </catalogsearch_mysql4>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: Exactly... This is maybe the last variation I didn't try. I think this is correct         <catalogsearch_mysql4_fulltext>
            <collection>My_Modulename_Model_CatalogSearch_Mysql4_Fulltext_Collection </collection>
        </catalogsearch_mysql4_fulltext>

Comment: Look in `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/etc/config.xml` and you will see there are model declarations for `<catalogsearch>` and `<catalogsearch_mysql4>`, this is where your rewrites will get merged to. It does not have a `<catalogsearch_mysql4_fulltext>` section so I doubt that will work.