# How do I add baseURL to images, and category name, to the Export function in Magento 1.4

Tags: php, magento-1.4

I'd like some advice on amending the export function in Magento 1.4.0.1.

I've created a profile that exports the products including the Image URL path and category ID.

Is it possible to insert the image folder URL before the image URL oath, and also replace the category ID with the name of the category?

Answer (score 0):

For Image Url, you can use

```
$image = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($your_product_id);

$thumbnail_path_url = $image->getMediaUrl($product->getThumbnail());
$smallimage_path_url = $image->getMediaUrl($product->getSmallImage());
$image_path_url = $image->getMediaUrl($product->getImage());
```

For Category name, you can use

```
$_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($your_category_id);
$catname = $_cat->getName();
```

Fetch these values separately and bind it to your existing fields.

What I provided was a general way of getting the Url path.
If you need to override the core magento Export functionality to add URL to image you can Check this 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789380/magento-advanced-profiles-export-prepend-url-to-image-path)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! How would I go about binding these as you've suggested? Would that involve editing the core files?

Comment: Yes, you need to override the Magento Core file.

Comment: Can you provide the path and file name to the files in question?

Comment: Check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789380/magento-advanced-profiles-export-prepend-url-to-image-path

Comment: I did as the article said but nothing's happened. The Actions XML looks exactly the same. I created the new files in,

app/code/local/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Mapper/MyColumn.php

and

app/code/local/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Profile/Collection.php

I also don't see where the code you've mentioned fits in to either of those files.

Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi, just to check - this will work with Magento 1.4, won't it?

Comment: I work on magento 1.9. I am not sure about Magento 1.4.

Comment: That's really not helpful when I mentioned the version twice!