# add product in new line if already exists in cart in magento

Tags: magento, cart

I want to add child product in the new line if it is already exists in the cart, I am able to check it is exists or not with below code but how can i add that with new line

```
$productId = 1;
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
if (! $quote->hasProductId($productId)) {
    // Product is not in the shopping cart so 
    // go head and show the popup.
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14174/how-can-i-show-the-same-product-multiple-times-in-the-shopping-cart

Comment: I hav checked that and with return false; it only stops item from adding but i want to add it in new line.

Comment: Can you try this one: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46604/same-product-added-to-cart-different-line-items It is a bit different approach.

Comment: Custom options will do the trick, you can either add it from Admin or programatically like in the second example.

Comment: I don't want to go with custom options

Comment: That's acceptable. We can find another way. But first, did I understood your question correctly: You want to check if a product is already in cart when add-to-cart action called, if that product is in cart you don't want to get qty increased, you want to add it like a new product in a new line?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Custom Options, you don't have any other option to differentiate your products in cart. So, you need to overload **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item** class and rewrite **representProduct** function.

[Create a custom module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento), [overload sales/quote_item model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575826/how-override-model-in-magento-correctly) and rewrite representFunction as below:

```
/**
 * Check product representation in item
 *
 * @param   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @return  bool
 */
public function representProduct($product)
{
    //You can check here if the product is the one that you need to add as a new line or not.
    if(/* some checks with $product */) {
        return false;
    }

    //run parent function as default
    return parent::representProduct($product);
}
```

So, any product added to cart will not represent another product -that already in cart- and be evaluated as a new product.

Comment: Thanks it works with all products but what if we want to work it only for related or any child product.

Comment: So you want to apply this only to a simple product that is linked to a configurable product?